# Cannot find module "./map.jsx"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

Whilst developing using react / webpack / node I reference other components using "import Map from './map.jsx';" or similar statements. I then webpacked to a bundle and attempted to host it on IIS along with an index.html page and the fonts folder. However in the console I get the error: Cannot find module "./map.jsx", as if it's trying to reference a local file, but I thought it was supposed to pack those into the bundle?

If there's anything else I can supply to assist troubleshooting, please let me know.

Here's my map.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import 'leaflet';

export default class Map extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.map = new L.Map('map', {
        center: new L.LatLng(53.15, 0.54),
        zoom: 8,
        layers: L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        })
    });
    this.layersControl = L.control.layers().addTo(this.map);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="map-container" className="pure-u-1">
        <div id="map"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and my app.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Nav from './nav/nav.jsx';
import NavButton from './nav/navbutton.jsx';
import Map from './map.jsx';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="pure-g">
        <Nav>
          <NavButton>Test</NavButton>
        </Nav>
        <Map />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

as well as the webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.jsx",
  output: {
      path: __dirname,
      filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader", query: { mimetype: "image/png" } },
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=fonts/[name].[ext]"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: "file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example so that it's possible to reproduce the issue? It's hard to say anything concrete without seeing your setup.

Comment: @bebraw I've updated the question, thanks.

Comment: Is it only that specific file you are having problems with? Can you add your webpack loader configuration as well?

Comment: @bebraw Added the config. If it makes any difference, the only files I try and host on IIS are the fonts output folder, bundle.js and index.html.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in your configuration. If you can set up a standalone example that generates the bundle, I could have a look at that. It's really weird it works during development but fails when bundled. Studying the bundled result (even unminified) might give you some insight.

Comment: @bebraw I'm quite new to Webpack, one thing I can't get my head around is the fact that in the bundle there are references to the local path trying to get the .jsx file.

Comment: @bebraw I actually just managed to get it to work by getting rid of -p in 'webpack -p'. -p is the minify right?

Comment: Yeah. `-p` enables `UglifyPlugin`. That sounds like really weird behavior, though.